# Warning when upgrading from PowerBuilder 10.5 to 12.5

Tags: powerbuilder

I was trying to migrate an application from PowerBuilder 10.5 to PowerBuilder 12.5. After successful migration, there are some warning. I am not able to resolve the warning. How can I resolve these warnings?

```
pfcapsrv.pbl(pfc_n_cst_trregistration).4: Warning     C0190: Instance variables of local structure type ('os_transentry') will be implicitly private in the next release.
```

Answer (score 1):

Since this is just a warning I would not worry about it too much.  Also, since Appeon Corporation has taken over the development of PowerBuilder from SAP, you can't really count on the warning to actually come to pass.

The object in your post is from the PowerBuilder Foundation Classes (PFC).  Have you downloaded the 12.6 version or are you upgrading the older one?  The link to the PFC downloads is [here](http://pfc.codeplex.com/).

Regardless, the message should not prevent you from running or compiling you application.

Answer (score 0):

From the "Project Painter" choose menu item "Design --> Options" and you can check/uncheck informational & Obsolete. Ignorance is bliss!

If you really want to resolve it than make your own implementation of the os_transentry structure and use it so you don't get nagged about it.

Answer (score -1):

as others told you ,
it's just an pfc upgrading warning , no need to worry .
but to make it obvious to you , if you are using this object , you have to handle this warning ,
but mostly as most of us , when upgrading these warnings will not affect you .
also to explain it , pfc libraries when upgrading and they want to remove or change old objects they maintain it in new release , not removing it .
for example , you have created user object to check authorities and implement system settings , and in new version you want to upgrade this way to be as separate user objects ,and application uses this object a lot , so you don't remove it , you just hide it from future use and make it as protected .